# Best experience for the user when loading up an iframe

Tags: user-expectation, branding

We're integrating our app into the Salesforce platform. For now, for this first version, we are simply loading up an iframe into Salesforce.

From a UX standpoint, would it be better to:

A. Style the iframe like the platform so it looks native to Salesforce, but still incorporate our logo in there

B. Style the iframe with respect to our brand. Meaning, this could look entirely different from Salesforce

Answer (score 1):

There are possible legal implications to leaving your content unbranded if the rest of the page is branded to Salesforce. Users could assume that your content belongs to Salesforce and may approach them to sort out any problems which could lead to your company being prosecuted for fraud by Salesforce for representing yourselves as them.

You need to take ownership of your content to avoid this and the best way to do that is to brand your content.

I understand your objections to having to styles of branding on the page but you should consult with your visual designers to make a mix of the two - One option might be to use Salesforce's typography and icons so that it blends well with the UI around the iFrame but use your logos and images to differentiate your content.